# How i can show image from database to page. Django

Tags: django, django-models

i have media directory in my project, and i can't take image from it. When i try getting image, then i got this 
Request URL:[http://127.0.0.1:8000/auto/media/img/'MyImg'.jpg](http://127.0.0.1:8000/auto/media/img/%27MyImg%27.jpg) and obviously it can't work, so how can i do this?
while doing this i am trying to get data in html like this

```
 {% for item in auto %}
    <div>
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
        <p>{{item.info}}</p>
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        <img src="media/{{item.photo}}">
    </div>
<hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Item model` do have the following:

```
class Item(models.Model):
     ...
     photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="path within media folder", null=True, blank=True)
     ...
```

In your `html` template you can call the `item.photo.url`. Like this...

```
<img src="{{ item.photo.url }}">
```